# Write the word 'M$\ddot{\rm u}$ller' in thebibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

With the following codes

```
     \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
     \mode<presentation>
      \usetheme{Madrid}
       \begin{document}
      \begin{frame}{}
     \begin{exampleblock}{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.50,0.00}{Theorem} 
      [M$\ddot{\rm u}$ller, Soltysiak (1992)]}
      For a $d$-tuple of ....
     \end{exampleblock}

    \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
     \bibitem{V. Muller, and A. Soltysiak}
    \alert{V. Muller, and A. Soltysiak}
   \newblock  {Spectral radius formula for commuting Hilbert space 
   operators}
   \newblock {\em Studia Math.103. (1992), 329-333}.
     \end{thebibliography}
     \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

However I fail to copmilate when I write `\bibitem{V. M$\ddot{\rm u}$ller, and A. Soltysiak}
        \alert{V. M$\ddot{\rm u}$ller, and A. Soltysiak}`, and I want to get

[image]

Comment: Müller. Müller. It is Müller

Comment: Or `M\"uller`, in **text mode**.

Comment: don't use math mode for people's names (or any text accents)

Comment: Letters like this should be covered in any good quality LaTeX instroduction.

Comment: Also with M\"uller I fail to compilate.

Comment: The argument of bibitem shouldnt have anything but letters and numbers to be honest. It is just a label.

Comment: I am not quite sure why you are using the manual approach https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References instead of a package like biblatex (ok, would be overkill for just two or three references)

Comment: Please don't use two letter font commands like `\rm`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Comment: In your previous question `\end{document}` was missing. Now `\end{frame}` and `\end{document}` is missing. Will you continue to remove one line for each question? :)

Comment: @samcarter I'm sorry, I will edit my questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your given code has a missing `\end{frame}` ...

With using `\"u` I can compile without errors:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
     \begin{exampleblock}{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.50,0.00}{Theorem} [M\"uller, Soltysiak (1992)]}
      For a $d$-tuple of ....
     \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame} % <=========================================================

 \begin{frame}
    \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
     \bibitem{V. Muller, and A. Soltysiak}
    \alert{V. M\"uller, and A. Soltysiak} % <===========================
   \newblock  {Spectral radius formula for commuting Hilbert space operators}
   \newblock {\em Studia Math.103. (1992), 329-333}.
     \end{thebibliography}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: When I copy your codes, it compilates However in my original document it doen't.

Comment: Now I delete `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in my original document and it compilates well. Where is the problem.

Comment: Thank you. The only difference is  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @Student, maybe your file has ISO encoding, not UTF8. Your editor should show this.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer already solves your problem with the umlaut. To go one step further use latex's bibliography mechanism and beamer theorem environment and let them do the formatting for you:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=green!40!black}
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \textcolor{orange}{\inserttheoremname}
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{theorem}[\cite{MS92}]
For a $d$-tuple of ....
\end{theorem}

\beamertemplatearticlebibitems
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[V. M\"{u}ller and A. Soltysiak (1992)]{MS92}
\alert{V. M\"{u}ller, and A. Soltysiak}
\newblock Spectral radius formula for commuting Hilbert space operators
\newblock \em Studia Math.103. (1992), 329-333.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I remark that always you delete `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Clearly when one write only in English, we don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. By the way is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` always not necessary in beamer?

Comment: @Student There is rarely an "always" in latex -- it all depends on the content of your file (the exception is that two letter font commands are always wrong to use in a current document).

Comment: @Student  If you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you will have to make sure that your file is encoded in utf8. If not change utf8 to the true encoding of your file,

Comment: @Student If your tex distribution is up to date (Texlive 2018) than `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used by default